# “Launch slave agent via Java Web Start” option not availabe whilce creating Node in jenkins v2.175

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, appium

In Global security, agents section no option for TCP port for JNLP agents,
there is only one option TCP port for inbound agents

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Both JNLP agents and TCP port for the inbound agent are same I guess. I mean if that is your question.